# How to get Bash colours in a Word or PDF document

Tags: bash, colors, microsoft-word

I've got a Bash script that outputs results with pretty Bash colours, and I need to include the output with colors in a Word document.

I would like to avoid putting a screenshot as the ouput is lenghty. I also don't really want to go through the pain of adding colours manually in Word so I am looking for an easy way to copy the text with colours in [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) and paste into Word with colours.

Comment: Not really a programming question. Try Super User?

Comment: I guess it's border line as it is more to document stuff, I'll look over there thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do a two-stage conversion, first to HTML then to Word. Try something like [ansi2html](http://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2008/08/19/ansi2html/), or [Ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/ansifilter.html) and then copy/paste from a browser into Word. Generating a PDF from HTML should also be trivial (ask if you need information).

Comment: ansi2html is what i needed, it works as a charm, thanks

Comment: "They do it wrong, so I'm going to do it wrong too" is rarely a valid excuse.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, "They weren't moved, so why should this one" ... is actually more the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can also record your bash session / command output with the `script` command. It preserves color escape codes and can be parsed accordingly. However, it needs further processing, no direct copy/paste possible.